# Build Chromium for multiple target_cpu

Tags: android, browser, chromium

I have been trying to compile Chromium for multiple target by specifying target_cpu to `Build.gn` as given below but nothing works, only single options like arm or arm64 are able to compile.

`target_cpu = ['arm64','arm']`  not supported by gn

`target_cpu = "arm64" | "arm"` not supported by gn

`target_cpu = "arm64"` // works

`target_cpu = "arm"` // works

How to compile chromium apk both `arm64` and `arm` platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target_cpu` must specify a single target, it doesn't support multiple targets. If it did, the debug symbols and files would be over written in your build folder.

So, you have to create a different build folder for each target

```
// For Arm architecture
gn gen out/arm

// For x86
gn gen out/x86
```

Then specify the arguments for each build target by executing:

```
gn args out/BUILD_FOLDER
```

Basically, it will open `args.gn` file located in `BUILD_FOLDER`. It will open that file in a text editor where you can specify `target_cpu` architecture along with other build flags. Then start the compilation process by executing

```
ninja -C out/BUILD_FOLDER chrome
```

Comment: Do you know the correct way to create an APK or AAB with all architectures for the Play Store? 

- Upload a separate file for each ABI?

- Adding different Lib folders to a single archive?

Comment: @AlexanderRoehnisch Sorry I don't do Android development but maybe this page can help you: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md